# How to tell bash not to expand aliases

Tags: bash, alias

I know there is a simple syntax for telling bash not to expand aliases. However, Google is not turning it up and I'm too lazy to read through man bash. Also, the answer should be on this website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put a backslash before the first character.

```
$ alias ls="echo foo"
$ ls
foo
$ \ls
bin
Desktop
Documents
  ...
```

Comment: By the way, this is not a bash-specific feature. It's mandated by POSIX, and works in bash, ksh and zsh amongst others.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `command` shell builtin command. It will execute only commands found in the `PATH` or shell builtins. It won't execute aliases or shell functions.

Example:

```
alias ls='ls -l'
$ ls
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 2010-10-11 13:17 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 4096 2010-10-15 15:37 dir2
$ function ls() {
> echo hello
> }
$ ls
hello
$ command ls
dir1  dir2
```

Answer (score 4):

Type `shopt -u expand_aliases` into the bash shell (the -u switch is for unset). I recommend reading the man page for shopt.

Answer (score 2):

As @bossNova has already suggested, to prevent alias expansion:

`shopt -u expand_aliases`

And for those who are curious, to set alias expansion:

`shopt -s expand_aliases`